# Wishlist (itemize) environment in .cls not working

Tags: color, environments, itemize, documentclass-writing

I made this wishlist environment in a .cls file. However, it is not working. Instead of a star, I get a dot. On the other levels as well, it is a totally normal list without any of the labels I specified. The code looks like this:

```
\newenvironment{wishlist}{\begin{itemize}{\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\color{orange}$\bigstar$}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\roman{enumii}}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\textendash}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{\alph{enumvi}}
    }}
    {\end{itemize}}
```

I used these packages to make the lables:

```
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pifont}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
```

Comment: Why you not use `enumitem` package. It is high flexible and enable simple adoption to your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The label is set up when `\begin{itemize}` is executed. Therefore redefining `\labelitemi` etc. from within an `\itemize` environment has no effect. The solution is to put your `\renewcommand`s before `\begin{itemize}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pifont}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}

\newenvironment{wishlist}{
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\color{orange}$\bigstar$}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\roman{enumii}}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\textendash}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{\alph{enumvi}}
    \begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{wishlist}
\item AAA
\item BBB
\end{wishlist}
\end{document}
```

[image: list]

Comment: If the icons for the different wishlist levels shouldn't be applied to other `itemize` environments, it would be a good idea to wrap another set of braces around the definition to make it a local group.

Comment: \roman{enumii} does not work. I guess it's because it is an unordered list? Is there an easy way to make it work, or is this complicated?

Comment: @barbarabeeton --- I can only see a problem if a wishlist appears inside an enumerate (or vice-versa), and I can't think of an easy way to fix that. That said, it's late here and I'm tired; if you can improve the code please feel free to edit.

Comment: @Vebjorn --- use `enumerate` rather than `itemize` and change `itemi` etc. to `enumi`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest `enumitem`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{wishlist}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[wishlist,1]{label=\textcolor{orange}{$\bigstar$}}
\setlist[wishlist,2]{label=\roman*}
\setlist[wishlist,3]{label=\textendash}
\setlist[wishlist,4]{label=\alph*}

\begin{document}

\begin{wishlist}
\item First (level 1)
\item Second (level 1)
  \begin{wishlist}
  \item First (level 2)
  \item Second (level 2)
    \begin{wishlist}
    \item First (level 3)
    \item Second (level 3)
      \begin{wishlist}
      \item First (level 4)
      \item Second (level 4)
      \end{wishlist}
    \end{wishlist}
  \end{wishlist}
\end{wishlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]